# Quiero realizar un script que me solicite ingresar un numero pero si el numero es 0 que termine la ejecucción del script plsql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, bucles, plsql

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED;
EXEC service_update;
DECLARE
  numero NUMBER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(NULL);
  LOOP
    numero := &INPUT_NUMBER;
    IF numero = 0 THEN
      EXIT; -- Salir del bucle si el número ingresado es 0
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EL NUMERO INGRESADO ES: ' || numero);
    END IF;
    IF numero <> 0 THEN
      CONTINUE; -- Volver a iniciar el bucle
    END IF;
    EXIT; -- Salir del bucle si el número ingresado es cero
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes con el script publicado?